# .net 6 mvc localization both in view and in javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, model-view-controller, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-localization

I wanted to share some important problem with localization (transilation of words in many languages) in javascript that i solved

this is the code in view that you use in view and you can you use in js as well

@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IViewLocalizer localizer

in view you can use like this

@localizer["addReference"].Value

in js you can use like this

@localizer["addReference"]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in view you can use like this
@localizer["addReference"].Value

in js you can use like this
@localizer["addReference"]

translation should be in double quatation mark such as "Add Reference" in resource.resx